# How to record data that is in a hidden section with prefilled link Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

How to record data that is in a hidden section with prefilled link Google Form

I have a form with 3 sections. The first section is for the user to input answers, after this section the users will be redirected to the third section and skip the second section. The second section is a hidden section that users will never redirected to this section. The third section contains only description then submit the form.

I prefilled the input in the second section using Google Form feature, then share the link to people.

[image]

[image: Pre-filled form feature]

[image]

After the user submits, I expect all input to be recorded to Spreadsheet (including the input in the second section), but actually it only records the first and third section. The section which the user has never visited is not recorded.

So, how can I still record the data in the hidden section even when the user has never visited?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) allows you to use Google Apps Script to access users' responses to a form. If the user hasn't responded, there will be no response. You can't access a response that doesn't exist. If you are prefilling the response yourself, may I ask why you need to record your own prefilled response?

Thanks for clarifying @Fanny Hasbi. Since you are only using the hidden section to store constant data and not user input, you would be better off passing your data to whatever script you are running on form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I already using Google App Script to control the responses. I need the hidden section so the user cannot edit it, because when the form is submitted it will trigger the App Script to perform some automated actions that need access key / secret key (which I store it in the hidden section). If the user edit the input, it will increase the risk of error.

Comment: Happy to help @FannyHasbi. If this answered your questing, please mark it as answered :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into this exact same issue, and I'd love to find a solution where this is possible. However, in the meantime, I've found a workaround and I wanted to share it here, even though it's been some time since your original question.

Instead of creating the question that you need for internal tracking info as a text item, instead create it as a multiple choice item, with only a single answer. Pre-fill that answer with the URL, and make the answer required. When the user accesses the Form, the answer will be chosen, and they won't be able to edit the text.

This is obviously less elegant than having a hidden section where the user doesn't see the internal data, but given Forms' limitations, this may be the best option for now. Here's how I have it set up in my script:

```
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setRequired(true)
    .setTitle('ID')
    .setHelpText('(for internal tracking purposes only)')
    .setChoiceValues([internalId]);
```

When you create the response for the prefilled URL, it's the exact same method as creating a response for a text item, so your script wouldn't need changing in that regard.

Hope that helps someone!